# Conditional order by with two different ordering on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

image table has fields `sortkey ,imageid`

I want that when all sortkey values of table are 0 than `order by image id.`and when all are not 0 than `order by sortkey ascending` and imageid after sortkey order.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM image 
WHERE 1=1  AND imageobjectid = 1 AND imagetype = 12 
ORDER BY CASE sortkey WHEN sortkey>0 THEN sortkey ELSE imageid END LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM image 
WHERE 1=1  AND imageobjectid = 1 AND imagetype = 12 ORDER BY 
(CASE sortkey WHEN sortkey>0 THEN sortkey END) ASC ,   
(CASE imageid WHEN !sortkey>0 THEN imageid END) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but nothing worked. 
Test cases :

```
(imageid,sortkey) : 
1. (1,0) (2,0)(3,0) -> output (imageid): 3 , 
2. (1,0) (2,1) (3,0) -> output (imageid) : 1 , 
3. (1,2) (2,1) (3,0) -> output (imageid) : 3
```

And i do not want to do it using subquery. It is possible to do with subquery but i am looking for solution with single query.

Comment: Your data shows a situation where all sort key values are neither all zero nor all not zero.  Maybe show us your expected output and we can go from there.

Comment: "All not zero" is not the same as "not all zero".

Comment: Added expected output.

Comment: If all sortkey are 0 and you order by sortkey, there won't be any ordering since they're all the same.

Comment: The expected output doesn't make sense, why is there only one number in each output?

Comment: I want that id as output.

Comment: There are 3 rows in the table, shouldn't there be 3 rows in the output?

Comment: I mean i want output with row of that particular id. If 3 reords with image id and sortkey combination as (1,0) (2,0)(3,0) than my output should contain first record as with id 3.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM image    ORDER BY 
if( (SELECT count(image.sortkey ) FROM image WHERE image.sortkey != 0 ) >= 1 ,imageid,sortkey) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM image order by sortkey asc, imageid asc;

this will order records in Sortkey order and then image id order, if sortkey is all zero then it will automatically turns to sort in imageid order

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this without some kind of subquery unless you use window functions.

```
select
    case when max(sortkey) = 0 then max(imageid) else
        (select min(imageid) from image i2 where i2.sortkey = min(i.sortkey))
    end as imageid
from image i
```